# Richtextbox SelectionFont.Size when multiple sizes are selected

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, controls

When a selection in WindowsForms RichTextbox uses two or more different font sizes (eg. you select text with font size 9 and some other text with font size 16 in the same selection), SelectionFont.Size always returns 13. Is there any way to detect that two different sizes are selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a range is selected which contains items that have the same font,
but different sizes, the control incorrectly reports that the selection contains a font with size 13. I'm not certain this can be fixed. Perhaps it's always 13 in this case, perhaps not, I don't know.

But i use the follow Solution ...
Found via Reflection in Methode

```
public class RichTextBox : TextBoxBase ...
  private Font GetCharFormatFont(bool selectionOnly)**
```

Example Code:
**Content => The RichTextBox-Control**

```
// var lSize = Content.SelectionSize;
var lSize = RichTextBoxHelper.GetSelectionSize(Content);

if (lSize.HasValue)
  ComboBoxFontSize.Text = Convert.ToString(lSize.Value);
else
  // Multible Sizes ...
  ComboBoxFontSize.Text = string.Empty;
```

Helper Methode (Class):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UnimatrixOne
{
  public class RichTextBoxHelper
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CHARFORMATA lParam);

    private const long CFM_SIZE = 0x80000000;
    private const int EM_GETCHARFORMAT = 0x043A;
    private const int SCF_SELECTION = 0x01;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Contains information about character formatting in a rich edit control. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks><see cref="CHARFORMAT"/>works with all Rich Edit versions.</remarks> 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public class CHARFORMATA
    {
      public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHARFORMATA));
      public int dwMask;
      public int dwEffects;
      public int yHeight;
      public int yOffset;
      public int crTextColor;
      public byte bCharSet;
      public byte bPitchAndFamily;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
      public byte[] szFaceName = new byte[32];
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets or sets the underline size off the current selection. 
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public static float? GetSelectionSize(RichTextBox control)
    {
      var lParam = new CHARFORMATA();
      lParam.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lParam);

      // Get the underline style 
      SendMessage(new HandleRef(control, control.Handle), EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, lParam);
      if ((lParam.dwMask & -CFM_SIZE) != 0)
      {
        float emSize = ((float)lParam.yHeight) / 20f;

        if ((emSize == 0f) && (lParam.yHeight > 0))
          emSize = 1f;

        return emSize;
      }
      else
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think that the only way of doing that is to loop through and check the font size of every single character separately.